# What text will smartctl output when the drive is not healthy

Tags: hard-disk, smartctl

I run this command to check drive health:

```
smartctl -H /dev/sda
```

Output:

```
smartctl 5.43 2012-06-30 r3573 [i686-linux-4.2.0-rc3+] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-12 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

What will be the output in case the disk is unhealthy? I don't have such disks and is unable to learn this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this (an SSD that reports this for 6+ months already):

```
# smartctl -H /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [x86_64-linux-3.16.0-4-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
Failed Attributes:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   043   043   090    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 57
```